# Applying specific function to all possible pairwise column combinations of a data frame

Tags: r

I need to get granger test's result of different pairs.

This is the function giving the needed result (`p_value`) and it works fine.

```
myFunction<-function(x,y)

{
  test<-grangertest(x~y,data=df)
  return(test$`Pr(>F)`[2])
}
```

This function works well, for example in this case:

```
myFunction(df$X48df886f9,df$X0deb4b6a8)
```

Now, I prepare all possible combinations:

```
list_1<-list(names(df))
list_2<-list(names(df))

combinations<-expand.grid(list_1,list_2)
```

Well to make this reproducible I select for you the first 6 variables

```
> df[1:50,1:6]
     target X48df886f9 X0deb4b6a8 X34b15f335 a8cb14b00 X2f0771a37
1  17.45310          0          0          0         0          0
2  13.30469          0          0          0         0          0
3  16.11810          0          0          0         0          0
4  14.50866          0          0          0         0          0
5  16.48274          0          0          0         0          0
6  14.84513          0          0          0         0          0
7  12.00763          0          0          0         0          0
8  13.30469          0          0          0         0          0
9  13.79429          0          0          0         0          0
10 13.03898          0          0          0         0          0
11 13.91082          0          0          0         0          0
12 16.58810          0          0          0         0          0
13 12.77706          0          0          0         0          0
14 15.76142          0          0          0         0          0
15 11.51294          0          0          0         0          0
16 13.59237          0          0          0         0          0
17 12.20608          0          0          0         0          0
18 15.09644          0          0          0         0          0
19 14.84012          0          0          0         0          0
20 10.59666          0          0          0         0          0
21 14.28551          0          0          0         0          0
22 14.99928          0          0          0         0          0
23 15.63034          0          0          0         0          0
24 16.51593          0          0          0         0          0
25 13.63319          0          0          0         0          0
26 12.89922          0          0          0         0          0
27 15.68731          0          0          0         0          0
28 14.34614          0          0          0         0          0
29 13.74652          0          0          0         0          0
30 15.20181          0          0          0         0          0
31 11.53274          0          0          0         0          0
32 16.81124          0          0          0         0          0
33 15.35596          0          0          0         0          0
34 16.81124          0          0          0         0          0
35 13.69898          0          0          0         0          0
36 15.60727          0          0          0         0          0
37 16.81124          0          0          0         0          0
38 14.50866          0          0          0         0          0
39 16.70588          0          0          0         0          0
40 15.67181          0          0          0         0          0
41 16.81124          0          0          0         0          0
42 16.11810          0          0          0         0          0
43 15.42495          0          0          0         0          0
44 16.01274          0          0          0         0          0
45 17.36334          0          0          0         0          0
46 15.20181          0          0          0         0          0
47 14.31629          0          0          0         0          0
48 15.31959          0          0          0         0          0
49 16.39573          0          0          0         0          0
50 16.11810          0          0          0         0          0
```

When I want to apply the test for all possible combinations, I used mapply as:

```
res_matrix <- mapply(myFunction,df[,which(names(df) %in% c(combinations$Var1))],df[,which(names(df) %in% c(combinations$Var2))])
```

But it returns empty result:

```
> res_matrix
named list()
```

How could I solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: What are the `x` and `y` argument of your function in term of `df`? Please do produce the reproducible example and I help you with `apply`, now it is to unclear for me.

Comment: @YoB., for example `df$X48df886f9` and `df$X0deb4b6a8`. and it works in this case

Comment: So `x` would be column `X48df886f9` and `y` would be column `X0deb4b6a8` ? The test uses the whole column each time, and you want it for every combination of 2 columns?

Comment: @YoB., yes exactly that. But when I replace `x` by only `X48df886f9`. It doesn't work. you should replace it by  `df$X48df886f9` as shown in the edited question.

Comment: and `target` has no impact in the game ?

Comment: @YoB., no you can use it as other columns

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposition, please ask for clarifications/modifications if needed. I do not have the `grangertest` so I put in a fake function.

```
data <- data.frame(target=runif(11), 
                   col1=0, col2=0, col3=0, 
                   col4=0, col5=0)

grangertest <- function(x,y){ # fake test
  length(x) * length(y)
}

outer(colnames(data), colnames(data), # pairwise operation
      FUN=Vectorize(function(a,b) grangertest(x=data[,a], y=data[,b])))
```

Comment: I am sorry.. Can you try producing the minimal reproducible example? If so, I can provide you with a working hack. Otherwise, I have to guess how your data are and it's less effective.

Comment: the problem that my dataset is too large. I say that you can use `df=df[1:50,1:6]`. Or as you propose. I think that is not an issue of data

Comment: so maybe it is the `grangertest`, can you provide the function? I just made a function that has 2 vectors as inputs, and that outputs one scalar. I think your test function does that but cant confirm. Does the data I generated fit yours?